# Calculate previous 12 months from given month - SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to get previous 12 month into an arraylist, from the given month(taken from DB).

```
List<String> allDates = new ArrayList<String>();    

sqlQuery="select max(date) from Table_Name";

maxDate="Jan-2016"; (Result from Query);
```

To get previous 12 months from maxDate,where i use SimpleDateFormat.

I want to calculate the previous 12 months from **Given Month** (maxDate), not from current month, i tried the following code.

```
//  Parsing maxDate to an integer (say Jan-2016 = 0, Feb-2016= 1)
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy").parse(maxDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        System.out.println("month : "+month);

// Looping to get previous 12 months from current month.
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
          for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -i);
                String month_name1 = month_date.format(calendar1.getTime());
                allDates.add(month_name1);
            }
            System.out.println(allDates);
```

Since months are numbered from **(0 - 11)** i couldn't achieve it.
Please suggest an idea to calculate previous 12 months from given month. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Do they need to be in descending order? Can you take away a year, then iterate forwards in time? Also, what type of object is `allDates` ?

Comment: I need it to be in descending order so that i can get previous 12 months. `allDates` here is an `ArrayList`. I need to add those 12 months to allDates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that in the loop you base the computation always from current date not from `maxDate`.

```
List<String> allDates = new ArrayList<>();
String maxDate = "Jan-2016";
SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(monthDate.parse(maxDate));
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    String month_name1 = monthDate.format(cal.getTime());
    allDates.add(month_name1);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
}
System.out.println(allDates);
```

output

```
[Jan-2016, Dec-2015, Nov-2015, Oct-2015, Sep-2015, Aug-2015, Jul-2015, Jun-2015, \
 May-2015, Apr-2015, Mar-2015, Feb-2015]
```

**edit** Short explanation what the snippet does.

1. create a `Calendar` from the given `maxDate` and assign it to `cal`
2. add the string `Mon-Year` of the current date in `cal` to the list `allDates`
3. substract one month from the calendar `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)`
4. repeat steps 2. and 3. twelve times

As mentioned by Basil. If you want to process the values in `allDates` later on as `Date / Calendar` think about not to generate a list of strings in between.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you please explain this line, `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);` I see that you have used `-1` instead of looping `i` ? And also i want Jan-2016 to be included into the ArrayList `allDates`, How can i achieve it?

Comment: @Disera I amend the snippet and add a short explanation what it does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

## ISO 8601

There is a sensible standard for representing date-time values as text: [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

So rather than serialize your year-month value as `Jan-2016` I strongly suggest you use the standard format, `2016-01`. This format is intuitive to read even across languages other than English.

## java.time

You are using the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. As you have learned, among their poor design choices is zero-based month numbers running 0-11.

Sun & Oracle gave up on those old classes, supplanting them with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

## `YearMonth`

Amongst those classes is just what you need: [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). As the name describes, a combination of a year and a month.

Rather than dealing in strings, pass objects of this type instead. You can rely on this class across your code base given that the class is built into Java.

### Parse

To parse your non-standard string, define a formatter. Specify a `Locale` for the human language by which to translate the name of the month.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = formatter.ofPattern( "MMM-yyyy" );
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
YearMonth stop = YearMonth.parse( "Jan-2016" , formatter );
```

To parse a standard string, no need for a formatter. The java.time classes support parsing/generating ISO 8601 strings by default.

```
YearMonth stop = YearMonth.parse( "2016-01" );
```

### Date-Time Math

The `YearMonth` class offers methods for adding and subtracting time.

```
YearMonth start = stop.minusYears( 1 );
```

Define a collection of type `YearMonth`.

```
List<YearMonth> yearMonths = new ArrayList<>( 12 );
```

Loop, incrementing a month at a time until we reach the stop month. You asked for the *Half-Open* approach where the beginning of the span of time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This Half-Open approach is common in date-time work.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = start ;
while ( yearMonth.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    yearMonths.add( yearMonth ) ;  // Add each incremented YearMonth to our collection.
    // Set up next loop.
    yearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths( 1 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Information!  `YearMonth` class is very useful.

Comment: Didn't find addMonths method on yearMonth object instance.
Instead, found this one in documentation: plusMonths(1). 
In this case you have to assign the result to iteration variable

Comment: @Tobet Yes, you’re right, I stand corrected. Code fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date()); //Give Your Date
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -12);
    Date fromDate = c.getTime();
    Date toDate = new Date(); //Give Your Date

    System.out.println("from "+fromDate);
    System.out.println(" to "+fromDate);
}
```

SQL Query:

```
select * from TABLE where Date between fromDate and toDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Not that I can see that you contribute anything towards the question that isn’t already in the other answers. I believe a list of 12 months was asked for.