# How to get list of passed months of this year java?

Tags: java, android, date-formatting

I am using SingleLine chart from PhilJay/MPAndroidChart android library and i need a list of passed months of current year. So for example from Jan to Oct, but when is October pass then from Jan to Nov and so on.
I tried these: [Getting List of Month for Past 1 year in Android dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556013/getting-list-of-month-for-past-1-year-in-android-dynamically),
and [Calculate previous 12 months from given month - SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797581/calculate-previous-12-months-from-given-month-simpledateformat)

but all of these are for previosly 12 months and i want from start of current year

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private void handleXAxis() {
    List<String> allDates = new ArrayList<>();
    String maxDate = "Jan";
    SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        cal.setTime(Objects.requireNonNull(monthDate.parse(maxDate)));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        String month_name1 = monthDate.format(cal.getTime());
        allDates.add(month_name1);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the month of the current date and then loop from 0 to month of current date - 1?

Comment: Calendar.MONTH start with 0.. 0 = JANUARY

Comment: Why don't you use `java.time.YearMonth`? Looks like that's nearly all you need... Seriously, don't use `Calendar` or any other outdated class for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr ⇒  `java.time`

**Months until (including) the current one as `List<YearMonth>`:**

```java
public static List<YearMonth> getMonthsOfCurrentYear() {
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now();
    List<YearMonth> yearMonths = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int month = 1; month <= currentMonth.getMonthValue(); month++) {
        yearMonths.add(YearMonth.of(currentMonth.getYear(), month));
    }
    
    return yearMonths;
}
```

**Months until (including) the current one as `List<String>`:**

```java
public static List<String> getMonthNamesOfCurrentYear() {
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now();
    List<String> yearMonths = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int month = 1; month <= currentMonth.getMonthValue(); month++) {
        yearMonths.add(YearMonth.of(currentMonth.getYear(), month)
                                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM",
                                                                    Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
    
    return yearMonths;
}
```

as an alternative, you can use the display name of the `Month` instead of using a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM")`

```java
public static List<String> getMonthNamesOfCurrentYear() {
    YearMonth currentMonth = YearMonth.now();
    List<String> yearMonths = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int month = 1; month <= currentMonth.getMonthValue(); month++) {
        yearMonths.add(Month.of(month)
                            .getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
    
    return yearMonths;
}
```

The output of the second and third example:

```
Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct
```

when invoked like

```java
System.out.println(String.join(", ", getMonthNamesOfCurrentYear()));
```